# В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект Unity

Tags: unity3d

```
public GameObject sphere, cube;
Vector3 newPos;
private void Update()
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Cube")
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unity выдает ошибку на этой строке

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
```

, пишет ссылка не указывает на объект. Из за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два варианта. Или у вас нету стандартной камеры. Возможно вы ее заменяли другой. Или не было касания к экрану. И если нет касания то соответственно нету и позиции касания. Но так как у вас входит в условие то скорее всего это из-за камеры. 
Советую вам продебажить этот момент. Или вывести в 
Debug.Log камеру и ваш тач. И посмотреть что из этого вызывает ошибку

Comment: Проблема оказалась в том что , камера должна иметь тэг MainCamera.

Comment: Вам об этом и сказали) Изначально когда создается сцена в ней есть камера, у которой стоит такой тэг, камера считается главной на сцене. Если ее удалить или сменить тэг, она перестанет быть таковой и `Camera.main` будет возвращать `null` (если конечно вы не назначите этот тэг другой камере и не сделаете ее главной).